# Why do you think this code isn't firing?

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

[image]

I don't have a lot of knowledge about xss so im kinda confused, why this is not popping up an alert box?

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Also, please describe what you are trying to achieve in the first place and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The input is **hidden**. It will never gain the focus and therefore the onfocus handler will never fire.